# Узнать id с помощью vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, python-3.8

Как узнать id юзера в вк с помощью модуля vk_api и его сокращенного имени(ссылки). Использую python 3.8
Всем заранее благодарен и попрошу максимально подробно описать как это сделать ведь я хочу не просто скопипастить код а и понять его.
Пробывал так, но получал ошибку :

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('логин', 'пароль')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()
api = vk.get_api()

text = vk.api.utils.resolveScreenName(screen_name='тут был пример')['object_id']

print(text)
```

Код ошибки :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 352, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    vk_session.auth()
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 177, in auth
    self._auth_cookies(reauth=reauth)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 197, in _auth_cookies
    self._vk_login()
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 247, in _vk_login
    response = self.http.get('https://vk.com/')
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Animeshnik_-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Answer (score 1):

`vk_session.method('utils.resolveScreenName', {'screen_name': пример})`

Попробуй так, но если ты хочешь реализацию через @, то у тебя не получится, потому что в сообщении это работает как

`[id1|@durov]`

А не

`@durov`

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется должно быть примерно вот так

`vk_session.users.getFollowers.user_id`

getFollowers - Возвращает список идентификаторов пользователей, которые являются подписчиками пользователя.

если нужно что другое можно посмотреть здесь

https://vk.com/dev/users

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то